# Error which i am incountering

Tags: database

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dropjob.semaphore' doesn't exist: SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => variable_init ) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of D:\drop_job\includes\lock.inc).

Can anybody help me to solve it
I will be greatful

Answer (score 0):

If the table doesn't exist (for some reason), you can create it manually by executing an sql query.

Here is the query to create the `semaphore` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `semaphore` (
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique name.',
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'A value for the semaphore.',
  `expire` double NOT NULL COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp with microseconds indicating when the semaphore should expire.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `value` (`value`),
  KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Table for holding semaphores, locks, flags, etc. that...';
```